# Loop Over to update Multiple Listboxes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

i have a small VBA Code in which it Contains 3 listBox and the list is based on the range defined. is it possible to do loop iteration for multiple list boxes `Sheet4.ListBox & i & .AddItem "Select All"`

here is my below code.

```
    Sub Test()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim MyRange As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESULT")
        last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 to 3 
        Set MyRange = ws.Range(Cells(2,i),Cells(last_row,i))
        Call update_listbox(i, MyRange)

End Sub

Sub(update_listbox)
'here i am updating my listing in ListBox

        Sheet4.ListBox & i &.Clear      ''Getting Error here    
        Sheet4.ListBox & i & .AddItem "Select All"  ''Getting Error here        
        Dim myList As Collection
        Dim myVal As Variant
        Set myList = New Collection
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
        myList.Add myCell.Value, CStr(myCell.Value)
        Next myCell
        On Error GoTo 0
        For Each myVal In myList
        Sheet4.ListBox & i &.AddItem myVal      'Getting Error here 
        Next myVal
End Sub
```

Please help. need other workaround if not posisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox & i` creates the string "ListBox1" or "ListBox2", etc. You cannot use this to identify the listbox object directly as you've tried but you can use the string to identify the listbox from a qualified collection.

Here are two methods of iterating through a worksheet's ListBox objects from the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code).

```
Option Explicit

Sub refLBs()
    Dim c As Object, i As Long

    For Each c In Me.OLEObjects
        Debug.Print c.Name
    Next c

    For i = 1 To Me.OLEObjects.Count
        Debug.Print Me.OLEObjects("listbox" & i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Me` is used in whenever a userform is  created . here i have not used any userform but instead an Form Object. will `Me` will work.? because it is giving me error as `invalid use of Me keybword`

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. your code do help me out. `Sheet4.OLEObjects`, i got the all the listboxes names.